# Continuity of piecewise function of two variables

Tags: calculus

The question looks like this. 
Let $f(x, y)$ = 0 if $y\leq 0$ or $y\geq x^4$, and $f(x, y)$ = 1 if $0 < y < x^4 $.

(a) show that $f(x, y) \rightarrow 0$ as $(x, y) \rightarrow (0, 0)$ along any path through (0, 0) of the form $ y = mx^a $ with $a < 4$.

(b) Despite part (a), show that $f$ is discontinuous at (0, 0)

(c) Show that $f$ is discontinuous on two entire curves.

What I've came to conclusion is that when $ x<0, m>0 $, and $a$ being an odd number, $y$ becomes smaller then zero, so $f(x, y)$ can't be any larger than zero. But I don't think that's not enough. I think I need to find a way to generalize that $ mx^a (a<4) $is larger than $x^4$ or smaller than 0 when $x$ and $y$ is close enough to zero, where I cant' quite get to.

In regarding (b), I know $f(x, y)$ is discontinuous on certain directions, but can't elaborate it in decent form.

In regarding (C), How can I show it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substitute $e^{-t}$ for $x$. In case $m=|m|$ then substitute $e^{-at+b}$ for $y$ where $b=ln(|m|)$, in case $m=-|m|$ then $y=-e^{-at+b}$. In the first case we have  $t>t_0=-b/(4-a) \Rightarrow y>x^4$ so $f(e^{-t},e^{-at+b})=0,\; \forall t>t_0$. In the second case we have $y<0 \;\forall t\in \Bbb{R}$ so that $f(e^{-t},-e^{-at+b})=0,\; \forall t\in \Bbb{R}$.

Comment: Thankyou. In addition, why is $f$ discontinuous at (0, 0)?

Comment: $f$ is discontinuous on the whole $x$-axis and on the graph of the curve $y=x^4$. The discontinuity arises because values suddenly jump from $1$ to $0$ without passing through all intermediate values. Like passing from black to white without passing through all the gray values in between.

Comment: Yup, understood. But how can I prove that in more elaborate manner? Shall I place an counter example? Ornis there any way to use epsilon-delta? Oh, and how can I prove the question (a) whem x is smaller than 0?

Comment: I didn't see that you edited the question. As for b) the epsilon-delta seems the more appropriate: given $U=(0.9,1.1)$ then $f(0,0)\in U$ and $f^{-1}(U)$ is not open (it has a border namely the quartic parabola $\cup$ the $x$-axis). For a) the situation is symmetric with respect the reflexion by the $y$-axis (i.e. we can replace $x$ by $-x$ without loss of generality).

Comment: Sorry for being unable tounderstand, but can I write like this for b)?

Comment: A function is continuous in a point $(0,0)$ if for every open neighbourhood $U$ of $f(0,0)$ the preimage $f^{-1}(U)$ is open. Since there is an $U$ for which the preimage $f^{-1}(U)$ is not open the function is discontinuous in $0,0$.

Comment: Okay.  But, if we approach (0, 0) along the y-axis, regardless of if y >0 or y<0, isn't it continuous? Is it considered discontinuous because there is no 'width' of the contacting point?

Comment: The function is continuous restricted to the $y$-axis since it is constant of value $1$ (same on . On the whole plane the function is discontinuous (and certainly at the origin).